# Access Glassfish server logs via REST

Tags: log-files, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.2. I have deployed Glassfish to localhost. I have enabled the monitoring service and set the log level to HIGH for all components.

[image]

I should be able to use the view the server logs at a REST end point at  `http://host:port/management/domain/view-log` according to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gjipx.html#gkwib), but I get a generic response:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/view-log
{"message":"","command":"Monitoring Data","exit_code":"SUCCESS"}
```

I get a proper response at this address, so I think my configuration is mostly correct:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/
{
   "message":"",
   "command":"Monitoring Data",
   "exit_code":"SUCCESS",
   "extraProperties":{
      "entity":{

      },
      "childResources":{
         "server":"http:\/\/localhost:4848\/monitoring\/domain\/server"
      }
   }
}
```

Note that the generic response I received is sent for any invalid endpoint under `domain`:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/jklnjkn
{"message":"","command":"Monitoring Data","exit_code":"SUCCESS"}
```

How can I access the Glassfish 3.1.2.2 server logs using the monitoring REST end point?

Answer (score 1):

I *just* spotted a typo in the documentation that lead me astray. The log files are available on the `management` path, not the `monitoring` path:

[image]

The log files are available on the `management` path, not the `monitoring` path. These are the correct resources:

- http://localhost:4848/management/domain/view-log
- http://localhost:4848/management/domain/view-log/details

Also, for some reason the `view-log` resource does not respond when you request JSON. The following request returns the log file:

```
$ curl http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/view-log
```

But this returns nothing:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:4848/management/domain/view-log
```

Does not.

`view-log/details` will respond with JSON if requested.

Comment: While I think this is a good answer, I would welcome more insight and explanation if anyone has something to offer.

Comment: FYI, I emailed the Glassfish documentation email address regarding this.